# R 4.2 não reconhece caracteres com acento

Tags: r, codificação-de-caracteres, acentuação

Alguém atualizou o R de 4.1.3 para 4.2.0 ou 4.2.1 e começou a ter problemas com caracteres acentuados, cedilhas etc? Estou usando o Windows 10. Tive alguns problemas como:

Toda vez que inicio o R, aparece esta mensagem:

```r
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/FernandoSim�oeSilva/Documents": O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado (System could not find the specified path).
```

Quando carrego uma library, dá este erro (mas carrega a library mesmo assim):

```r
> library(openxlsx)
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

E, quando eu leio algum arquivo txt ou csv com funções como readLines e read.csv, caracteres acentuados saem desformatados (e não adianta colocar o argumento `encoding = "UTF-8"`):

```r
[2] "Par<e2>metros            C<f3>digo da          Unidade                  Resultados       Faixa Aceit<e1>vel de                   ID da Corrida"          
[3] "Par\xe2metros            C\xf3digo da Amostra                  Unidade                 Resultados                             ID da Corrida Anal\xedtica"
```

Se eu simplesmente configurar o RStudio para trabalhar com o R 4.1.3 e fizer as mesmas coisas, nenhum desses problemas acontece. Mas eu não posso trabalhar com a versão antiga do R para sempre. Alguém já passou por isso e encontrou uma solução?

Comment: Você pode nos dar um exemplo reprodutível?

Comment: Quanto à mensagem de warning ao abrir o RStudio, para reproduzir o erro, é só questão de ter instalada a versão 4.2.1 do R e a versão 2022.02.3.492 (penúltima) do RStudio, e então abrir. O mesmo vale para carregar libraries.

Quanto ao erro com leitura de caracteres especiais, eu precisaria anexar um arquivo aqui para ler com readLines ou read.csv. Porque, se criar um arquivo com o próprio R e depois ler, dá certo. Dá errado se o arquivo foi criado fora do R.
```r
> writeLines("Acentos: á ã à é", "teste.txt")
> readLines("teste.txt")
[1] "Acentos: á ã à é"
```